# Is it possible to install Minergate in Lubuntu, for 32-bit?

Tags: lubuntu, 32-bit, bitcoin

Has anyone been successful in running Minergate software in Lubuntu? I just want to maximize my extra workstation for Minergate only. My workstation is 32-bit and not 64-bit by the way.

Comment: I'm currently upgrading to 16.04, I've seen mostly 64-bit and as a newbite in Lubuntu, I was just wondering if anyone is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Minergate, I was able to use my Lubuntu system for a little bit of mining using [xmrig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/wiki/Ubuntu-Build)

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of MineGate 8ю3 are [64-bit only executables](https://minergate.com/downloads/gui):

[image: modern versions of MinerGate]

and old versions too:

[image: previous versions of MinerGate]

So consider to reinstall 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: sigh, I guess I should just find other mining software which can be good for 32-bit architecture since my extra one is only 32-bit. i was just hoping if anyone has ever tried it on a 32-bit pc.